# Sharepoint Designer encountered an error generating the task form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have made some minor changes on `Approval workflow` in the `production environment` using the `SharePoint Designer 2013`. This workflow was working properly earlier.

It shows

> `The workflow contains no errors`

when i click on check for errors.

But when i click on the publish button, the SharePoint designer encountered an error saying that

> "SharePoint Designer encountered an error generating the task form".

And when i clicked OK, the publishing process finished. And now the Approval email is not getting generated.

Workflow start automatically -- when item is changed.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I re-created the workflow and it was published successfully. Now the workflow is running smoothly. Now the error has gone but i still don't know the root cause for the error i was facing.